# Erratic javax.jms.JMSException: Peer disposed

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I have a erratic problem with Java JMS.
For moments works fine, but throws the following exception erratically and cut the execution.

It is important to note that this occurs without stopping the broker.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://test#1) disposed.
        at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:49)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1773)
        at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1790)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:114)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:99)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.iterate(VMTransport.java:203)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://test#1) disposed.
```

Comment: You'd need post some more info, sample code etc so we can help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it *could be* this issue with ActiveMQ: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-2902

This issue tracker thread says that it is harmless (it is just a noisy INFO level log message), and that it is fixed in ActiveMQ 5.4.2.

On the other hand, you say that the exception *"cut the execution"* ... which *could* mean that this is a different issue to yours ...

**UPDATE**

Anyone getting a "peer disposed" exception that isn't fixed by upgrading ActiveMQ, and isn't related to shutdown (see [Unable to shutdown embedded activeMQ service using the built in BrokerService.stop call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591203)) should consider lodging a bug report.

Comment: It would seem the poster's issue is completely different, unless I'm missing something.  The link mentions a noisy INFO level log message, but the above (which is also what I'm getting) is a thrown JMSException, which has these additional lines under the Caused by: clause.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem the poster's issue is completely different.  The link mentions a noisy INFO level log message, but the above (which is also what I'm getting) is a thrown JMSException, which has these additional lines from the `Caused by:` clause.

```
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:88)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.oneway(ResponseCorrelator.java:60)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1275)
    ... 31 more
```

The odd part is that there is a connection.isClosed() check before it gets this far.  So the connection is open, but the 'peer' is still disposed.  From researching other potential answers online, the only possible solution is that the connection to the broker is intact, but the specific queue may be closed.

For my particular similar case, this occurred when the broker was stopped, but consumers and producers were still attempting to establish connections.  Sometimes the connection would still be considered open (i.e., *not closed* even though the broker was stopped).  Fixing this to ensure the broker did not die fixed my problem.

I also wanted to add that this issue I've seen in ActiveMQ 5.6 (but I haven't tested in 5.8).

Comment: you should lodge a bug report for this.

Answer (score 0):

this is version compatibility issue, this exception is causing due to Spring boot version and Active MQ version is not compatible with each other

so for spring boot version 3.1.3 I have installed ActiveMQ 5.18.2 version it got resolved automatically

```
2023-09-15T18:00:15.675+05:30  INFO 2200 --- [           main] c.nt.BootMsp2PProducerApp1Application    : Starting BootMsp2PProducerApp1Application using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 2200 (D:\WORKSPACE\BootMSP2P-ProducerApp-1\target\classes started by Shree in D:\WORKSPACE\BootMSP2P-ProducerApp-1)
2023-09-15T18:00:15.681+05:30  INFO 2200 --- [           main] c.nt.BootMsp2PProducerApp1Application    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-15T18:00:16.756+05:30  INFO 2200 --- [           main] c.nt.BootMsp2PProducerApp1Application    : Started BootMsp2PProducerApp1Application in 1.566 seconds (process running for 2.173)
***Message Sent***
```