# Unable to shutdown embedded activeMQ service using the built in BrokerService.stop call

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I have been using an embedded activeMQ server configuration (configuration is very similar to the examples that illustrate the concept of an embedded activeMQ server/listener). 
As part of the application, I have a monitoring thread that monitors a directory. Instead of having to kill the process to shutdown the activeMQ server, I introduced a check for a "STOP" file  and if the file exists, the server would shutdown. 
The shutdown I am trying to accomplish by calling the stop function on the broker:

`(broker.stop() )`

This seems to shutdown the service. However, Upon a `System.exit`, Exception errors are raised:

I observed that one other post that mentioned similar behaviour had a response that indicated as much as "This is normal" behavior.  One other post indicated that I should disable the shutdownhook (via Spring config of the broker by setting the `useShutdownHook="false"`).  This has not fixed the problem either.

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the exception stack trace:

```
17:10:20.056 [Thread-9] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer - Failed to send remove command: javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#3) disposed.
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#3) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1267) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.asyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1259) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.dispose(AdvisoryConsumer.java:56) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:615) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:426) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:321) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.destroy(SingleConnectionFactory.java:312) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://localhost#3) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:89) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.oneway(ResponseCorrelator.java:60) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1265) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
17:10:20.069 [Thread-9] DEBUG o.s.j.c.SingleConnectionFactory - Could not close shared JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#3) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doSyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1342) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:660) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:426) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:321) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.destroy(SingleConnectionFactory.java:312) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://localhost#3) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:89) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:91) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doSyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1329) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
17:10:20.069 [Thread-9] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy() on bean with name 'jmsProducerConnectionFactory'
17:10:20.069 [Thread-9] DEBUG o.s.j.c.SingleConnectionFactory - Closing shared JMS Connection: ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:u0102180-MacA.local-57101-1331074458547-2:1,clientId=ID:u0102180-MacA.local-57101-1331074458547-3:1,started=false}
17:10:20.070 [Thread-9] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer - Failed to send remove command: javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1267) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.asyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1259) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.AdvisoryConsumer.dispose(AdvisoryConsumer.java:56) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:615) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:426) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:321) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.destroy(SingleConnectionFactory.java:312) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:89) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.oneway(ResponseCorrelator.java:60) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doAsyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1265) [activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
17:10:20.071 [Thread-9] DEBUG o.s.j.c.SingleConnectionFactory - Could not close shared JMS Connection
javax.jms.JMSException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:62) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doSyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1342) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.close(ActiveMQConnection.java:660) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.closeConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:426) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.resetConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:321) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.destroy(SingleConnectionFactory.java:312) [spring-jms-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:211) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:498) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:474) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:442) [spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1066) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1040) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:958) [spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://localhost#1) disposed.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.oneway(VMTransport.java:89) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:40) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:91) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.doSyncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1329) ~[activemq-core-5.5.1.jar:5.5.1]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
```

(@TimBish - Thanks for the comment)

Comment: Just saying exceptions are raised doesn't help much, you should add some context on what exceptions you are seeing.

Answer (score 19):

ActiveMQ registers its own [shutdown hook](http://activemq.apache.org/broker-uri.html) and stops automatically when the process is terminating. Thus it is already stopped before you've called stop() and the exception appears.

If you are stopping it manually via Spring then you should disable the shutdown hook by setting the property **useShutdownHook="false"**

```
<broker brokerName="broker" useShutdownHook="false">
```

Comment: Than Andrejs your suggestion worked for me, although I'm using *yml config file with spring-boot. This is my broker-url: `spring.activemq.broker-url: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&broker.useShutdownHook=false`. Now the exceptions are gone from my integration tests!

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the shutdown hook by setting this broker url:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&broker.useShutdownHook=false.
```

Now the exceptions are gone from my integration tests!

But in maven build, it fails the integration test again with an error:

```
Failed invoking method{}
reactor.core.Exceptions$ReactiveException: java.lang.InterruptedException
at reactor.core.Exception$ReactiveException:java.lang.InterruptedException
```