# Getting TransportDisposedIOException : Peer (vm://ipaddress#3) disposed. in active MQ

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, activemq-classic

1. I just used this sample code to implement Active MQ http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/12/20/integrating-activemq-tomcat-using-global-jndi#ex-tomcat-server-xml.
2. Able to send and receive the message successfully with tomcat server.
3. Now I required to implement Shared File System Master Slave. For that I have followed the steps below to change activemq.xml configuration
4. Added networkConnector and transportConnector in activemq.xml

   ```
   <networkConnectors>
       <networkConnector name="My Queue" uri="static://(tcp://172.16.121.144:61616,tcp://172.16.121.146:61616)" />
   </networkConnectors>

   <transportConnectors>
       <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://172.16.121.144:61616"/>
   </transportConnectors>
   ```

---

activemq.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
      http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.3.0.xsd">
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" />  
        <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" 
                brokerName="172.16.121.144" 
                dataDirectory="\\172.16.121.145\Shared Doc\amq\activemq\activemq-data"
                schedulerSupport="false"
                useJmx="true"> 
            <destinationPolicy>
                <policyMap>
                    <policyEntries>
                        <policyEntry topic=">">
                            <pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                                <vmCursor />
                            </pendingSubscriberPolicy>
                        </policyEntry>
                        <policyEntry queue=">">
                            <pendingQueuePolicy>
                                <vmQueueCursor />
                            </pendingQueuePolicy>
                        </policyEntry>
                    </policyEntries>
                </policyMap>
            </destinationPolicy> 
            <managementContext>
                <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
            </managementContext>
            <networkConnectors>
                <networkConnector name="My Queue" uri="static://(tcp://172.16.121.144:61616,tcp://172.16.121.146:61616)" />
            </networkConnectors>
            <persistenceAdapter>
                <kahaDB directory="\\172.16.121.145\Shared Doc\amq\activemq\activemq-data\kahadb"/>
            </persistenceAdapter>
            <systemUsage>
                <systemUsage>
                    <memoryUsage>
                        <memoryUsage limit="128 mb"/>
                    </memoryUsage>
                    <storeUsage>
                        <storeUsage limit="1 gb"/>
                    </storeUsage>
                    <tempUsage>
                        <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
                    </tempUsage>
                </systemUsage>
            </systemUsage>
            <transportConnectors>
                <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://172.16.121.144:61616"/>
            </transportConnectors>
        </broker>
    </beans>
```

5. Getting below exception

   ```
    INFO  - ContextLoader                  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
       INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext       - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Aug 20 12:31:15 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy

       INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader        - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/jms-context.xml]
       INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@bc6a12:defining beans [connectionFactory,fooQueue,singleConnectionFactory,jmsTemplate,messageSenderService,jmsMessageDelegate,myMessageListener,org.springfra
       mework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer#0]; root of factory hierarchy
       INFO  - DefaultLifecycleProcessor      - Starting beans in phase 2147483647
       INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1bc3ec9:
        defining beans [org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService#0]; root of factory hierarchy
       INFO  - BrokerService                  - Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[\\172.16.121.145\SharedDoc\amq\activemq\activemq-data\ka
       hadb]
       INFO  - BrokerService                  - ActiveMQ 5.4.1 JMS Message Broker (172.16.121.144) is starting
       INFO  - BrokerService                  - For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org/
       INFO  - TransportServerThreadSupport   - Listening for connections at: tcp://01hw385526:61616
       INFO  - TransportConnector             - Connector openwire Started
       INFO  - DiscoveryNetworkConnector      - Establishing network connection from vm://172.16.121.144?async=false&network=true to tcp://172.16.121.144:616
       16
       INFO  - TransportConnector             - Connector vm://172.16.121.144 Started
       INFO  - DiscoveryNetworkConnector      - Establishing network connection from vm://172.16.121.144?async=false&network=true to tcp://172.16.121.146:616
       16
       INFO  - DemandForwardingBridgeSupport  - 172.16.121.144 bridge to 172.16.121.144 stopped
       INFO  - Transport                      - Transport failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://172.16.121.144#3) di
       sposed.
       org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://172.16.121.144#3) disposed.
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:159)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportServer$1.stop(VMTransportServer.java:81)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132)
               at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.dispose(ServiceSupport.java:43)
               at org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector.onServiceAdd(DiscoveryNetworkConnector.java:137)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryAgent.start(SimpleDiscoveryAgent.java:77)
               at org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector.handleStart(DiscoveryNetworkConnector.java:186)
               at org.apache.activemq.network.NetworkConnector$1.doStart(NetworkConnector.java:61)
               at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:53)
               at org.apache.activemq.network.NetworkConnector.start(NetworkConnector.java:202)
               at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startAllConnectors(BrokerService.java:2094)
               at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:518)
               at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.afterPropertiesSet(XBeanBrokerService.java:60)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
       :1581)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522
       )
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
               at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
               at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)
               at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)
               at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:96)
               at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:52)
               at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)
               at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doCompositeConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:121)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportFactory.doConnect(VMTransportFactory.java:53)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.doConnect(TransportFactory.java:51)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFactory.connect(TransportFactory.java:80)
               at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createTransport(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:243)
               at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:258)
               at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:230)
               at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:178)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
               at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
               at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
               at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
               at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:196)
               at $Proxy4.createConnection(Unknown Source)
               at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
               at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:404)
               at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:372)
               at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:760)
               at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:279)
               at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:264)
               at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:561)
               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:167)
               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$1(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:154)
               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:339)
               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143)
               at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:108)
               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:926)
               at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
               at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
               at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
               at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
               at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
               at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
               at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
       INFO  - TransportConnector             - Connector vm://172.16.121.144 Stopped
       INFO  - DemandForwardingBridgeSupport  - Network connection between vm://172.16.121.144#2 and tcp://172.16.121.146:61616 shutdown due to a local error
       : org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://172.16.121.144#2) disposed.
       INFO  - DemandForwardingBridgeSupport  - 172.16.121.144 bridge to Unknown stopped
       INFO  - NetworkConnector               - Network Connector My Queue Started
       INFO  - BrokerService                  - ActiveMQ JMS Message Broker (172.16.121.144, ID:01hw385526-51685-1376982077589-0:0) started
       INFO  - TransportConnector             - Connector vm://localhost Started
       INFO  - ContextLoader                  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3479 ms
       INFO  - DispatcherServlet              - FrameworkServlet 'jms-webapp': initialization started
       INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext       - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'jms-webapp-servlet': startup date [Tue Aug 20 12:31:18 IST 20
       13]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
       INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader        - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jms-webapp-servlet.xml]
       INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory     - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@e975db:
       defining beans [jmsMessageSenderController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context
       .annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.contex
       t.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web
       .servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; p
       arent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@bc6a12
       INFO  - DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/send.html] onto handler 'jmsMessageSenderController'
       INFO  - DispatcherServlet              - FrameworkServlet 'jms-webapp': initialization completed in 375 ms
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
       INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\docs
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
       INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\examples
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
       INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\host-manager
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
       INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\manager
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
       INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\ROOT
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
       INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
       Aug 20, 2013 12:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
       INFO: Server startup in 4825 ms
       INFO  - DiscoveryNetworkConnector      - Establishing network connection from vm://172.16.121.144?async=false&network=true to tcp://172.16.121.146:616
       16
       INFO  - TransportConnector             - Connector vm://172.16.121.144 Started
       INFO  - Transport                      - Transport failed: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://172.16.121.144#7) di
       sposed.
       org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://172.16.121.144#7) disposed.
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:159)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransportServer$1.stop(VMTransportServer.java:81)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:65)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132)
               at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.dispose(ServiceSupport.java:43)
               at org.apache.activemq.network.DiscoveryNetworkConnector.onServiceAdd(DiscoveryNetworkConnector.java:137)
               at org.apache.activemq.transport.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryAgent$1.run(SimpleDiscoveryAgent.java:164)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
       INFO  - DemandForwardingBridgeSupport  - Network connection between vm://172.16.121.144#6 and tcp://172.16.121.146:61616 shutdown due to a local error
       : org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: Peer (vm://172.16.121.144#6) disposed.
       INFO  - TransportConnector             - Connector vm://172.16.121.144 Stopped
       INFO  - DemandForwardingBridgeSupport  - 172.16.121.144 bridge to Unknown stopped
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erratic javax.jms.JMSException: Peer disposed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078637/erratic-javax-jms-jmsexception-peer-disposed).

Comment: tnx Tomas, After replacing 5.4.2 jar able to up master node tomcat. But not able to up the slave node tomcat. It is waiting for that Shared File. Once down the master node tomcat, slave node tomcat getting up. How can I start the both the tomcat