# Spring Boot application unexpected shutdown with no reason

Tags: spring, spring-boot, shutdown

Sometimes my Spring Boot application is shutting down with no clear reasons.

I can only see the following output in the appliaction log:

```
2019-09-02 01:39:16.199  INFO 23535 --- [ActiveMQ ShutdownHook] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.9 (localhost, ID:example-33285-1567372309839-0:1) is shutting down
2019-09-02 01:39:16.216  INFO 23535 --- [ActiveMQ Connection Executor: vm://localhost#0] o.s.j.c.CachingConnectionFactory         : Encountered a JMSException - resetting the underlying JMS Connection

javax.jms.JMSException: peer (vm://localhost#1) stopped.
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:54) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onAsyncException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1960) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.onException(ActiveMQConnection.java:1979) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:114) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.onException(ResponseCorrelator.java:126) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.onException(TransportFilter.java:114) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.vm.VMTransport.stop(VMTransport.java:233) ~[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:72) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportFilter.stop(TransportFilter.java:72) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.stop(ResponseCorrelator.java:132) ~[activemq-client-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.doStop(TransportConnection.java:1194) ~[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection$4.run(TransportConnection.java:1160) ~[activemq-broker-5.15.9.jar!/:5.15.9]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportDisposedIOException: peer (vm://localhost#1) stopped.
    ... 9 common frames omitted

2019-09-02 01:39:16.218  INFO 23535 --- [Thread-7] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2019-09-02 01:39:16.218  INFO 23535 --- [ActiveMQ ShutdownHook] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://localhost stopped
2019-09-02 01:39:16.225  INFO 23535 --- [Thread-7] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-09-02 01:39:16.230  INFO 23535 --- [ActiveMQ ShutdownHook] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.9 (localhost, ID:example-33285-1567372309839-0:1) uptime 1 hour 27 minutes
2019-09-02 01:39:16.230  INFO 23535 --- [ActiveMQ ShutdownHook] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.9 (localhost, ID:example-33285-1567372309839-0:1) is shutdown
```

I have no idea what is a cause of this shutdown. What steps should I do in order to determine the reason?

Comment: Try setting this property in `application.properties/yml` `spring.activemq.broker-url: vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false&broker.useShutdownHook=false`

Comment: Take a loom at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6078637/erratic-javax-jms-jmsexception-peer-disposed